# StringProperty Operator embedded in panel for responsive textfield

Tags: python, scripting

I am stuck with a simple problem, which it does not seem to have a simple solution.

All I want is to make a check for duplicate items by its name after entering a string in my UI.
This was previously done by a registered `bpy.props.StringProperty` from a  `bpy.types.PropertyGroup` by defining the appropriate update function.

Now I wanted to have a "Info" report every time I get a duplicate.
As for my understanding, this should be done by using `bpy.types.Operator`. Since I have to use an Operator I can no longer use the update function of a StringProperty. But when I try to solve this with an Operator I cannot get a simple text field working which triggers the `execute` after a word is typed. All I get is a button which triggers the desired action when pressed.

How can I draw an operator as a simple text field in between my other UI elements?

best regards

Comment: Why don't you just call the operator you need from inside of the update function? If you need it to behave like if it was called by user, just pass 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' as its first argument. If you want your operator to look like text in UI, pass `emboss=False` as `operator()`'s argument in the draw method.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It works to call the function and everything, but somehow the `self.report(..)` call only prints to the console instead both the console and the Info window. When I tried some different code I experienced the same behavior. If the operator is called in the code there is no output to the Info panel...